# Jquery to find an replace text after last slash in an image src url

Tags: jquery, image

I know the question i've posted here is quit silly but after hours of googling and trying all most everything i could not get the desired result. So let me share it here in a hope to get solved here.

My problem is, i've an Image url source where i need to change Image name with new image name everytime.
I'll post my tried code:

```
$(function () {
     //Old Image Url where i need to change 32_Penguins.jpg with new file name
     var ImageSrcUrl="../Upload\UserProfile\32_Penguins.jpg"; //Don't change forward slash with backword slash here and then try to answer
     var NewFileName="Tullips.jpg";

     //I tried to replace everything after the last "\"[slash]
     ImageSrcUrl= ImageSrcUrl.replace(/.*$/i, NewFileName); 

     alert(ImageSrcUrl);
});
```

Note: Please don't try to replace forward slash with backward slash manually and then answer it[Bcoz it works but conversion should be done via jquery code not manually]

Comment: images path contains backword or forword slash?

Comment: I double checked my code and found that problem was in my Image tag where i was giving src attribute. Sorry everyone for giving burden, and thanks everyone for solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
     //Old Image Url where i need to change 32_Penguins.jpg with new file name
     var ImageSrcUrl="../Upload/UserProfile/32_Penguins.jpg";
     var NewFileName="Tullips.jpg";

     var parts = ImageSrcUrl.split('/');

     parts[parts.length -1] = NewFileName;
     alert(parts.join('/'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
      //Old Image Url where i need to change 32_Penguins.jpg with new file name
      var ImageSrcUrl = "../Upload\\UserProfile\\32_Penguins.jpg";
      var index = ImageSrcUrl.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1;
     var path = ImageSrcUrl.substr(0,index);
     var NewFileName="Tullips.jpg ";
     ImageSrcUrl= path+NewFileName; 
     alert(ImageSrcUrl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try to change to lastindexof("\\") @Amar and write `ImageSrcUrl` escaping `\` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
     var ImageSrcUrl = "../Upload/UserProfile/32_Penguins.jpg";

     var NewFileName = "Tullips.jpg";
     var index = ImageSrcUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
     var filename = ImageSrcUrl.substr(index);
     ImageSrcUrl = ImageSrcUrl.replace(filename, NewFileName); 
     alert(ImageSrcUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**I wrote an example for this one:**

$(function () {
    var str = "ss/ll/Test.jpg";
      var m = /[^/]*$/.exec(str)[0];
      var sts = str.replace (m, "Tst.jpg");
      display("Input: " + str);
      display("Replaced: " + sts);

      function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = msg;
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your initial function:

```
function aa() {
    var ImageSrcUrl="../Upload/UserProfile/32_Penguins.jpg";
    var NewFileName="Tullips.jpg";
    ImageSrcUrl = ImageSrcUrl.replace(/[A-z0-9.]*$/i, NewFileName); 
    return ImageSrcUrl;
};
```

From what I tested it should work.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I did change the `\\` because AFAIK urls don't have them.